# jQuery Combobox/Combify/Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, autocomplete

I'm currently trying to implement a dropdown/text input combination similar to jQuery combobox (can be seen here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

Essentially, the input should suggest an answer based on the select options, but if they want to type something other than the select options in to the form, they can (and the form needs to retain the same  group name).

The selects are being added by jQuery on the click of a button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $wrapper = $(".GCSE_wrap");
    var $add_button = $(".add_field_button");
    var appendGCSE = '<li class="ui-state-default gcse_results_wrapper"><div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="Subject[]" class="form-control spec_one gcse_subject" placeholder="Subject"></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one gcse_level" name="SubjectLevel[]" placeholder="GCSE?"></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><select name="GCSEGrade[]"  class="form-control spec_one gcse_grade"><option value="A*">A*</option><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option><option value="c">C</option><option value="D">D</option><option value="E">E</option><option value="F">F</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one gcse_year" name="GCSEYear[]" placeholder="Year"></div><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary cas_btn copy_to_all">C</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary close_btn remove_field">X</a></li>';
    $add_button.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $wrapper.append(appendGCSE);
        $("#gcse_sort").trigger("sortupdate");
    });
```

});

I tried using the plugin Combify but this was not successful, since it would not accept any input other than the options set out in the select (http://jsbin.com/vixesa/edit?html,js,output)

Could someone please point me to a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used an input with an autocomplete instead.